# Return query with complex where condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table like this

table `allotment`

```
allotment_id | date | room_id | is_closed
-----------------------------------------
1 | 2017-01-28 | 21 | 0
2 | 2017-01-29 | 21 | 1
3 | 2017-01-30 | 21 | 0
4 | 2017-01-31 | 21 | 0
5 | 2017-01-28 | 32 | 0
6 | 2017-01-29 | 32 | 0
7 | 2017-01-30 | 32 | 0
8 | 2017-01-31 | 32 | 0
```

I was try query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM allotment
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-28' AND DATE_SUB('2017-01-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND is_closed = 0
AND date >= '2017-01-28' AND l.`date` <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND allotment_id NOT IN (select allotment_id FROM allotment WHERE is_closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-28' AND date <= '2017-01-31')
```

As you can see I select from date 2017-01-28 until 2017-01-31 and there is two room id on table which in **room_id** 21 date 2017-01-29 **is_closed** is 1.

What I want is return just **room_id** 32 because in **room_id** 21 where date range I selected it was value 1 in **is_closed**.

I have tried my query but it doesn't working. How could I to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: in where and subquery you have taken allotment_id. instead of this you must take **room id**

Comment: Showing us your expected output might be helpful here.

Comment: have you tried my answer ?

Comment: @krishnpatel it works sir. thank you.

Comment: @Antonio can you up the ans ?

Comment: done sir. @krishnpatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in where and subquery you have taken allotment_id. instead of this you must take room id

```
SELECT *
FROM allotment
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-28' AND DATE_SUB('2017-01-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND is_closed = 0 and room_id not in (select room_id FROM allotment WHERE is_closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-28' AND date <= '2017-01-31')
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this questions [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686054/merge-two-rows-in-mysql-database-table-with-condition]

Answer (score 0):

Group by the room and take only those having zero times the `is_closed` flag

```
SELECT room_id
FROM allotment
WHERE date >= '2017-01-28' 
  AND date <= '2017-01-31'
group by room_id
having sum(is_closed = 1) = 0
```

Comment: Be more specific than that

Comment: It still return room_id 21 because in 2017-01-28 there is value 0 in is_closed

Comment: I am pretty sure that can't be if you use my query. Are you sure?

Comment: @Antonio it does work definitely.[**See demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce5226/1).