# Merge two rows in mysql database table with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql database and in that table I do some query to display result from the table. But I want to merge some row in my table.

This is the structure and example value of my table.

```
id | benefit | plan_day | price
-------------------------------
1 | Free Pick up | 100 | 540
2 | Free Tea | 100 | 540
```

That example have same value in **plan_day** but different value in **benefit**.

This is my second example with different in **plan_day** and **benefit**

```
id | benefit | plan_day | price
-------------------------------
1 | Free Pick up | 110 | 540
2 | Free Tea | 100 | 540
```

What I want to know is I want to merge that two rows with condition if the value in **plan_day** is the same I just want merge **benefit** and the **price** is not `SUM` but if **plan_day** have different value I want to merge **benefit** and that **plan_day** itself and I want to `SUM` the **price**.

This is result I want to display :

Condition if **plan_day** have same value.

```
Free Pick up, Free Tea | 100 | 540
```

Condition if **plan_day** have different value.

```
Free Pick up, Free Tea | 110, 100 | 1080
```

And this is what I have been do but not success.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(benefit SEPARATOR ',') AS benefit, GROUP_CONCAT(plan_day SEPARATOR ',') AS plan_day, SUM(price) as price
FROM special_offer
```

Anyone can help me with this issue ? Thank you.

Comment: What happens when all those four rows are present together? What happens if the plan_day was same but prices were different?

Comment: I just want to display one. @GurV

Comment: Which one? Please clarify how it will work in that case?

Comment: what do you mean ? @GurV I think I already explain clearly about my questions.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `DISTINCT` clause to your query:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT benefit SEPARATOR ',') AS benefit,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT plan_day SEPARATOR ',') AS plan_day,
  SUM(price) as price
FROM
  special_offer
```

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited my questions in part of query and result what I want. I change `SUM(price) AS price`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select plan_day,
    group_concat(benefit order by id separator ',') benefits,
    max(price) price
from t
group by plan_day
having count(*) > 1

union all

select *
from (
    select group_concat(t1.plan_day order by t1.id separator ',') plan_day,
        group_concat(t1.benefit order by t1.id separator ','),
        sum(t1.price) price
    from t t1
    join (
        select plan_day
        from t
        group by plan_day
        having count(*) = 1
        ) t2 on t1.plan_day = t2.plan_day
    )
where plan_day is not null;
```

For this data:

```
(1, 'Free Pick up', 110, 540 ),
(2, 'Free Tea',     100, 540 );
```

Produces:

```
110,100     Free Pick up,Free Tea   1080
```

And for data

```
(1, 'Free Pick up', 100, 540 ),
(2, 'Free Tea',     100, 540 );
```

Produces:

```
100         Free Pick up,Free Tea   540
```

Comment: When plan_day is different it's return empty.

Comment: @Antonio - No it doesnt. See the first example output.

Comment: do you have other simple query ? not with union like that ?

Comment: With your requirements, no.